# nginx: ignore case when using alias

Tags: nginx

I have a lot of static files whose name follows the following pattern:

> sku_(no)_1.jpg, sku_(no)_2.jpg, sku_(no)_3.jpg...

Where (no) is a 6 digit number.
Because there are so many of them, I have to put them into different directories and use the `alias` directive to redirect the requests, like:

```
location ~* (sku_\d+(\d)(\d)(\d)_\d+)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ {
    alias /path_to_directory/$4/$3/$2/$1.$5;
}
```

Now the difficult part is that sometimes the requests come with upper case, for example the request for file `sku_101138_1.JPG` would go to
/path_to_directory/8/3/1/sku_101138_1.**JPG**
However the actual file is stored as
/path_to_directory/8/3/1/sku_101138_1.**jpg**
this would lead to a `404 not found`

So how can I tell nginx to ignore case when using `alias` directive?

Comment: Is it really a problem? How this wrong links could appear?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Because there are some historical issues which cause the database to store the origin file ext. while the image handler has been changed to store file with lower-cased file names. of course I need to fix it, but I don't want to enumerate tens of thousands of images to change their names. Kind of looking for a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [map](http://nginx.org/r/map) directive.

```
# must be defined outside of server block
map $ext   $ext_lower {
    ~*jpg  jpg;
    ~*png  png;
    ~*jpeg jpeg;  
    ~*gif  gif;
}

location ~* (sku_\d+(\d)(\d)(\d)_\d+)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ {
    # set named variables
    set $name $4/$3/$2/$1;
    set $ext $5;
    alias /path_to_directory/$name.$ext_lower;
}
```

Here I have to point to two things:

1. `map` must be outside of any `server` block and it's global for all nginx config.
2. We have to define named variables before using `$ext_lower`, because as soon as we use it, it will ruin all positional variables (`$1`, `$2`, ...) because of using regular expressions. So `alias /path_to_directory/$4/$3/$2/$1.$ext_lower;` will not work, because `$1`-`$4` will be empty.

Comment: Nice. Never thought I can use the `map` here.